# The architecture of one producer and several consumers in getting market data from Stock Exchange

Tags: architecture, apache-kafka, message-queue

I have a scenario that I need to use one producer (stock exchange) that provide market data. Each market data message contains ("symbol", "price" and "timestamp").

Meanwhile, I have 3 consumers (servers) and each of them will consume market data with certain "symbol". For example, consumer a will only consume market data that has symbol "AAPL", "AMZN", consumer B will consumer that has symbol "GOOS" and so on.

One requirement is that the consumers have to receive timestamp-ordered messages for the symbols they want.

There is another requirement that consumers may change their preference from time to time. Like consumer A may start to consume message with symbol "GOOS".

How should I design this architecture? I know I may need to take advantage of Kafka MQ, but I am not an expert in this. Could someone please elaborate on how the design would be?

Comment: I am curious on how did you finalized to Kafka. Have you evaluated other messaging platforms - http://queues.io/

Comment: Hi @Andy, I don't have to use Kafka, but just want to see whether Kafka provides more functionalities. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I have been into the same boat. I am trying to figure out a messaging platform that matches our business requirements and that's where I came across the above link. From your requirements it seems you need a topic based messaging platform (vs a queue based). You can check AWS SNS and see if suits your needs. The advantage it has is it is managed by AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your design *could* contain the following components**:

*Data Acquisition Layer*: A component that will source data from the exchange and will have a Kafka producer embedded to be able to send data to Kafka.

*Messaging Layer*: This will be your Kafka cluster (multiple brokers, let's say 3 to enable replication). On this Kafka cluster you'll need to create a topic (let's say `raw-market-data`) with multiple partitions. For example, if you've got 300 symbols in total so you could choose to create 100 partitions (numbered from 0 to 299) with each partition ending up with 3 symbols.

*Consumption Layer*: This is where your consumers will run. You've already mentioned that you'll have 3 instances of this consumer.

**Other design considerations**:

*Partitioning strategy*:

- The Kafka producer running in the data acquisition layer could structure the message as `{7, { "stockSymbol": "AAPL", "marketPrice": 57.10, "timestamp": "May 13th, 10:03:18 AM "} }`. The digit `7` in the beginning of the message i.e. the key of the message indicating which partition this message should go to. You'll need to write the logic within the producer which would map a particular stock symbol to a dedicated partition.
- Another option could be to structure the message as `{"AAPL", { "stockSymbol": "AAPL", "marketPrice": 57.10, "timestamp": "May 13th, 10:03:18 AM "} }`. You explicitly push the stock symbol in the key of the message and then Kafka's default partitioner will jump in and calculate the hash of the string `AAPL` and do a modulo with the number of partitions. The result of this calculation will then determine the partition where this message will end up in. This option has a caveat that the symbol distribution across the partitions may not always be uniform. Here's a reference to [the actual source code of the default partitioner](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java) if you'd like to study it yourself.
- The third option is to write your own custom partitioner. Here's a [reference article with an example](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/06/04/write-apache-kafka-custom-partitioner/).
- The actual number of partitions will depend on various other factors such as total throughput, number of brokers, number of consumer instances i.e. unit of parallelism etc.

*Consumption strategy*:

- Typically, the consumer instances will be assigned partitions automatically by Kafka - the default assignment is done using the `RangeAssignor`. For example, if you've got 8 partitions (numbered from 0 to 7) and 3 consumers (c1, c2 and c3) then Kafka will assign partitions `{0, 1, 2}` to `c1`, `{3, 4, 5}` to `c2` and `{6, 7}` to `c3`. You could either assign specific partitions to a particular consumer by literally calling the `assign()` method or write your custom assignor by implementing [this interface](https://github.com/Paulf-999/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/PartitionAssignor.java).
- On your requirement for ordering the messages according to the timestamp. Now, this is something that Kafka cannot guarantee. The messages will be pushed to the topic in the order they arrive so if there are 2 messages with timestamps `t1` and `t2` with `t1 < t2` and because of some reason the message with `t2` timestamp arrives first then this will be consumed before the message with `t1` timestamp. You'll therefore need to deal with this in your consumer application instance - I've used `TreeMap` data structure in the past with `timestamp` as the key to achieve this.
- On the requirement of changing the consumption preferences - it might be best if you implement your custom partition assignor (mentioned in point 1 of consumption strategy) which will enable you to deal with this as this is a very specific requirement.

I've mentioned design considerations that were related to the requirements stated in your question. There would be more as we go deeper but this should probably give you a starting point.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Lalit, thank very much for your detailed answer. That makes thing much clear for me. However, I still have a question about how the consumer can filter out the message it wants at different time. Think about this scenario: at 8am, consumer A wants to consume Stock AAPL, AMAN and BHP and these three are in partition 0. But at 9am, consumer A want to start to consume GOOS and EDU. How this can be achieved?

Comment: Well, this is a really interesting one. I've been thinking about this for a while but still trying to work through some of the ideas. It might actually be useful to put this as a new question and invite opinions from the rest of the community as well. Could you please share the link to the new post here if and when you post it? I'll try and work through the ideas in and come back.